# Why is $\left\lvert e^{i\Im(s)\log(n)}\right\rvert = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $|e^{it}|=1$ for any real $t.$

Answer (score 2):

Recall $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$.  So if $x$ is real, then $|e^{ix}| = (\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)^{1/2} = 1$.